# ImageView not centred in View

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I have created an `ImageView`, which I aligned to be centred, as the dotted blue line indicates when the Image is horizontally centred. However, when I run the app in the emulator, it instead appears off to the left. I recently unchecked "Use size classes" in the Attribute Inspector so make the view iPhone screen shaped rather than square, but I don't believe this was the cause.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What Auto Layout Constraints are you using?

Comment: There's no code currently, I centred it in the view using the main Storyboard :)

Comment: In the File Inspector, "Use Auto Layout" is ticked.
Edit: And "Use Size Classes" is unticked.

Comment: You dragged the image view to the centre in ImageBuilder, but did you actually set constraints to centre it?  Select the image view and then select "Align->Horizontal Center in container" and "Align->Vertical centre in container" from the "Editor" menu

Comment: This works :) Thank you! Though now I'm getting a massive ImageView with the error "Misplaced View: Frame for image will be different at runtime." But thanks nonetheless!  
  
Edit: I solved the Misplaced View error by selecting the image and going Editor -> Resolve Auto Layout Issues -> Add missing Constraints.

Answer (score 0):

select the view in storyboard and remove the constraints to get desired output .here is the screen shot

[image]

Comment: Size inspector says the view has no constraints :\

Comment: Don't worry, a comment above's fixed the problem :)